# inline styles for tabs in material ui doesn't change color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am new to material ui and am trying to change the colors for the selected tab.

Right now it's dark blue in color and I am trying to change it to red.

I gave the inline styles, but it's not changing.  Can you tell me how to fix it?

I am providing my sandbox and code snippet below

https://codesandbox.io/s/yqj5q8v461

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  scrollable
  scrollButtons="on"
  indicatorColor="primary"
  textColor="primary"
>
  <Tab
   label="Search"
   icon={<PhoneIcon />}
   style={{ border: "red" }}
  />
  <Tab
   favorites={favorites}
   label="Favorites"
   icon={<FavoriteIcon />}
  />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override the styles of tabs using CSS API,

as an example:

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  scrollable
  scrollButtons="on"
  classes={{ indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}
>
  <Tab
   label="Search"
   icon={<PhoneIcon />}
   classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected }}
  />
  <Tab
   favorites={favorites}
   label="Favorites"
   icon={<FavoriteIcon />}
   classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected }}
  />
</Tabs>
```

then I have added styles as:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  tabsIndicator: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  tabRoot: {
    "&:hover": {
      color: "red",
      opacity: 1
    },
    "&$tabSelected": {
      color: "red",
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium
    },
    "&:focus": {
      color: "red"
    }
  },
  tabSelected: {}
});
```

here is a working example from your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/882o65xlyl

hope this will help you

Comment: thanks so much...can you tell me why your using this symbols &$, so that inm future I will fix it myself &:

Comment: hey one more question I tried to capitalize both the words, but its changing only on selected and hover, is it possible to change it in normal state too https://codesandbox.io/s/2pomwq2z20

Comment: hey can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-tetxbox-go-down

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `border: '1px solid red'`

Comment: thanks for your reply...but it should change only for the selected tabs...providing updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/yqj5q8v461

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Material UI uses JSS to style its components, so you'll need to use a withStyles wrapper around your components if you want to style the MUI components. here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/m36q74kn7x

Comment: thanks for your reply...hey it worked but can you tell me how you find out indicator will fix the issue, I looked into the tutorial but I didnt able to understand...can you help me...so that I will fix the css for other components

Comment: You need to go to the [Material UI website](https://material-ui.com) and navigate to the "Component API" dropdowns. From here you go to the "Tabs" option and scroll to the "[CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#css-api)" section. These listed name/description pairs are the possible keys for the `classes` object on the component. I just looked here and saw that indicator was listed. You should also read up on the "overriding with classes" writeup that they [provide](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes)

Answer (score 0):

if you interested other design framework, I recommend you Ant-design.

You can check for the inform [here](https://ant.design/)