# css position absolute making the textbox go down

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- I build a prototype using chips material-UI.

  - When I click the **Test IPA** the textbox should show immediately below the text Test IPA.
  - In the prototype, it shows immediately below but whereas when I include with other functionalities, it's showing at the bottom.
- I debugged the CSS, its due to position absolute for each scenario it's showing different values and its coming from material UI.
- Can you tell me how to fix it with respect to other components?
- Providing my code snippet, sandbox and bug screenshot below.

Problem with other components
https://codesandbox.io/s/qqqk23x3q

[image]

Working properly individually
 https://codesandbox.io/s/1y2mvo0ol3

JSX:

```
<td>
    <ChipsTextbox chipName="test IPA" />
</td>

<Menu id="simple-menu" open={open} onClose={this.handleClose}>
    <TextField onChange={this.onChange} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} />
</Menu>
```

CSS:

```
.MuiPopover-paper-1706 {
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 16px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 32px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 16px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 32px);
}
```

Comment: The project in first link have many errors. Kindly resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

The parent element of the `.MuiPopover-paper-1706` should have `position: relative` CSS attribute. If it doesn't then the element with `position: absolute` will be positioned relatively to the nearest parent with relative positioning.