# trying to remove padding from the ul tag of the popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- when I click chip chipName="button test IPA" a popup opens.
- I am trying to remove padding from the ul tag of that popup.
- but the problem is I am not able to find the ul tag in my html of jsx.
- I gave className in the react code but still I am not able to target
- can you please help me so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing code snippet below

https://codesandbox.io/s/qqqk23x3q

**tab-demo.js**

```
<td>
                    <ChipsButton
                      className={classes.chipContainer}
                      chipName="button test IPA"

                      // menuItems={IPAMenuItems}
                      //ChipsButton
                    />
                  </td>

              **chips-dialog.js**

                  <Menu
          className={classes.chipButtonContainer}
          id="simple-menu"
          // anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem className={classes.chipButtonContainerHeader}>
            {this.state.menuText}
          </MenuItem>

          <Button
            className={classes.chipButtonContainerButton}
            key={1}
            style={{
              backgroundColor:
                this.state.menuText === "Active selected" ? "green" : ""
            }}
            // style={{ display: this.state.display ? "none" : "" }}
            // aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            value={"Active"}
            onClick={this.handleSelect}
          >
            Active
          </Button>
          <Button
            key={2}
            style={{
              backgroundColor:
                this.state.menuText === "Inactive selected" ? "green" : ""
            }}
            value={"Inactive"}
            // style={{ display: this.state.display ? "none" : "" }}
            // aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleSelect}
          >
            Inactive
          </Button>
        </Menu>


        const styles = theme => ({
  chipButtonContainer: {
    border: "1px solid brown",
    padding: "0"
  },
  chipButtonContainerHeader: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    border: "1px solid pink"
  },
  chipButtonContainerButton: {
    border: "1px solid black"
  }
})
```

;

Comment: There's not enough here to go on. We can't reproduce your problem with the given code.

Comment: @Will sorry forgot to paste the sandbox link....updated the question

Comment: That is a lot of code. Looks like this class is the culprit: .MuiList-padding-270 {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}

Comment: @Will how to remove that padding...is there any way can we overwrite MuiList

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forward [`MenuListProps`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v3.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/Menu/Menu.js#L124) to the underlying [`List`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v3.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/List/List.js#L49) component ([`MenuList`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v3.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/MenuList/MenuList.js#L127) composes with this) to disable padding applied to it.

This edit can be made in `chips-dialog.js`

```
<Menu
   className={classes.chipButtonContainer}
   //...
   MenuListProps={{ disablePadding: true }}
   onClose={this.handleClose}
>
<!--...-->
</Menu>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...it worked...can you tell me how you found out so that in future I will fix it myself...

Comment: can you help me withis question too...I am stuck with this for past one week https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-tetxbox-go-down

Comment: I start with exploring the proptypes available in the component in the source code for the component and seeing which affect the design. Seeing that `MenuListProps` was being forwarded let me know to check if there was a way to set the padding either using classNames or  a special prop.

Answer (score 1):

Works the same for the `<Select>` component with `MenuProps`

```
<Select
    multiple
    input={<Input />}
    MenuProps={{
      MenuListProps: {
        disablePadding: true
    }}>
    {employees.map((employee) => (
    <MenuItem key={employee.id} value={employee.id}>
        {employee.name}
    </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Select>
```