# material ui border color overwriting the texbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- when I intially load the page the border color of the text box should be red in color.
- but the problem is its showing grey color.
- so I gave border color: red to all the classes.
- but still it doesnt change.
- not sure how to target this tag.
- i achieved by giving important. is it possible to achieve without giving important
- can you guys let me know so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/m58841kkwp

```or-tag-here
 cssLabel: {
    "&$cssFocused": {
      color: { borderColor: "red" }
    }
  },
  cssFocused: { borderColor: "red" },
  cssUnderline: {
    "&:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "red"
    }
  },
  cssOutlinedInput: {
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green"
    }
  },
  notchedOutline: { borderColor: "red !important" },



   <div className={classes.container}>
      <TextField
        className={classes.margin}
        InputLabelProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.cssLabel,
            focused: classes.cssFocused
          }
        }}
        InputProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
            focused: classes.cssFocused,
            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
          }
        }}
        label="Custom CSS border"
        variant="outlined"
        id="custom-css-outlined-input"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Normally you could avoid using !important by making the css rule a higher specificity, but since you're using styled components instead of rules in a css file i dont think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `CustomizedInputs-notchedOutline` class is being overwritten by the `MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline` class, the output css is something like this:

```
.CustomizedInputs-notchedOutline-1356 {
    border-color: red;  //this is your class
}

.MuiOutlinedInput-root-1382 .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline-1389 {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);   //this is the class that is overwriting yours
}
```

You have to use or create a stronger selector to the element something like this:

```
.more.class {    //multiple class selector
    border-color: red; 
}
```

Note: if you have access to the class that is overwriting yours just change it.

EDIT: 
As I told you, you can use a stronger selector, add `& $notchedOutline`selector to  `cssOutlinedInput` something like this:

```
cssOutlinedInput: {
    "& $notchedOutline": {   //add this nested selector
       borderColor: "red",
    },

    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
       borderColor: "green"
    }
}
```

and of course remove the `!important` from `notchedOutline: { borderColor: "red !important" },`

Comment: hey I see different numbers outside the class CustomizedInputs-notchedOutline-1356, we cant use the numbers since each time the numbers might change....is there anyway can we fix it

Comment: @injiinji that number are related to the context of react so you cant't use it. my advice is to add another class to `CustomizedInputs-notchedOutline` element so you will have 2 classes to reference the element thus that will be a stronger selector and will overwrite the `MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline`.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in my sandbox so confusing :( https://codesandbox.io/s/m58841kkwp

Comment: @injiinji I edited my answer  to guide you using a stronger selector, I try it in your sandbox and it works, please let me know .

Comment: hey I updated your code in sandbox its not working, can you check your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/m58841kkwp is it possible for you to update in sandbox and paste the link...so confusing :(

Comment: @injiinji you can't remove the entire rule `notchedOutline: { borderColor: "red !important" },` just the `!important`, in fact you can leave the style empty like this : `notchedOutline: {},`

Comment: hey its working now, but still I didnt understand...can you tell me why you guys used & symbol

Comment: @injiinji that is to reference the component itself, when you want to nest a selector in original css will be like `.parent .child {}` so in that case to reference the `child` inside `parent` is like `& $child`, if it works I will appreciate if you upvote and check as resolve my answer. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: is there any documentation for this selectors, since I am new to material UI

Comment: can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-textbox-go-down

Comment: @injiinji about selector try this https://cssinjs.org/?v=v9.8.7 and https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v8.6.1

Comment: thanks...can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-textbox-go-down

Comment: is there any way can we remove this padding, since I needed smaller text box .MuiOutlinedInput-input-41 {
    padding: 18.5px 14px;
}