# sticky footer not staying at the bottom after I scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- i am trying to develop a sticky footer.
- when you click **add new sports button a drawer opens in that footer stays at the bottom**.
- but when I scroll the page the footer is moving up.
- I am tried with various positions but still not working. can you tell me how to fix it.
  -providing my code snippet, sandbox and screenshot below.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/jp82jl853v

```
 sportsEditTabContentFooter: {
    position: "fixed",
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: "100 %",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center"
  },


  <div className={classes.sportsEditTabContentFooter}>
              <div>sports Status</div>
              <div>
                <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button}>
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button
                  variant="outlined"
                  onClick={this.savesports}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  Save sports test
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you tried `position: sticky;`?

Comment: @gearsdigital hey it worked thanks, can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-textbox-go-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code it looks like you have not applied the position:sticky to the div. If you add that you should notice it sticks where you have positioned it.

```
.RecipeReviewCard-sportsEditTabContentFooter-649 {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: hey it worked thanks, can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-textbox-go-down

Comment: @injiinji What an attitude is that? You should at least accept this answer before forcing an answer to another question!

Comment: Also, if you copy this code make sure to remove the duplicated position declarations which @robert-perez probably overlooked ;)

Comment: Good call gearsdigital, I'm going to edit that in order to make sure no one gets confused.